# Why is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac yx \ne 0$?

Tags: limits

If I have the two following limits:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x} \tag1$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y}{x} \tag2$$

Can someone explain to me, in a very elaborate way, why is the first equal to $0$, and the second not?

Comment: What definition of $\lim$ do you want to use? Note that $x\mapsto \frac0x$ is the constant zero-function everywhere except at $x=0$ (where it is undefined) while $\frac yx$ is a function with a very ugly behaviour around $0$.

Comment: You want it explained in a very elaborate way? You mean, using category theory, and cohomology groups, and Euler systems?

Comment: Depending on your definition of the limit with two variables, it can be 0.

Comment: @AlexR I roughly understand that the first limit is equal to zero. But I don't see why y/x, or any function with multiple variables, continous on (0,0), doesn't follow the same rules.

Comment: It is discontinuous at (0,0).

Comment: @Anixx It's undefined on (0,0) yes, but other examples that are continuous, such as $\frac{x²y²}{x²+y²}$ which is continous on (0,0), but can be related to this same issue, confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first limit, the value of $\frac0x$ is constant and equal to $0$ for all values of $x\neq0$. This means that the closer $x$ gets to $0$, $\frac 0x$ will remain equal to $0$. In this case, the definition of the limit clearly states that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$.

On the other hand, when $x$ and $y$ go to zero simultaneously, they can do it in many different ways. You can of course think that $y=0$ and fall back to the preceding case. Then the answer *could be* equal to $0$. But if $x$ and $y$ are equal and go both together to $0$, the ratio $\frac xy$ would be constant and equal to $1$. So the answer *could also be* $1$. From these remarks, as $0\neq1$, there is no value possible for the second limit.

The way to reconcile the two is to make $y$ go to zero *first* and then $x$. That would be written as
$$\lim_{x\to0}\;\lim_{y\to0}\frac yx=0.$$

Comment: Hmm, is it always correct to `make y go to zero first and then x` in order to calculate these sort of limits?

Comment: @Zee. No of course. But this defines a trajectory in the $(x,y)$ plane. One can use another trajectory and get (or not) another limit, but at least this well defined. $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ is not well defined.

Comment: So for all functions with multiple variables, if I can find "trajectories" to get more than one limit, then the function has no limit in the point specified?

Comment: @Zee. Yes, it's exactly what I meant to say !